# Results are different while retrieving HD videos using V2 and V3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on YouTube API. I doing analysis on V2 and V3. At present I tried to retrieve the HD videos. The output is not matching when I am using same query.

Using V3

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=football+-soccer&start-index=1&max-results=10&videoDefinition=high&key={Developer key}`

Using V2

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2&hd&alt=jsonc`

Where V3 is stable? or should I continue with v2 for my project.

Comment: Why so urgent? We are not in the mood to answer immediately yet.

Comment: That was a hint on NEVER using words "immediately" and other forms of orders on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better of building on top of API V3. V3 is where most of our current investment is going and we're adding new features as well as bug fixes to V3. Also, I recommend checking out Topics API, more information here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic, Topics will help you obtain more reliable (semantically) search results. Only API V3 supports the Topics API.

Comment: Thanks jarek. But using the Freebase Topics, i cant able to retrieve the hd videos. Can u help me to frame the url for retrieving HD videos  with appropriate video id as response. And another query is why the output of v2 and v3 are not matches.